# What does the entity framework context look like? does it read from web.config?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How is the session or context in entity framework configured?

Does it pull the connection string from the web.config?

And does it handle connection pooling also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework context is usually configured using the app.config file for a standalone application or the web.config file for a web app, the connection string is part of this configuration. There is an overloaded constructor though that will allow you to "manually" pass in a connection string to be used if this default does not work for you.

The EF context is just a wrapper over a SQL connection, so if the underlying connection supports connection pooling - i.e. [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) - this will work the same way with an EF context.

Comment: Isn't it more than that?  Does it manage change tracking/dirty entities etc?